# Qt with OpenSSL and gRPC yields linkage problem

Tags: android, c++, qt, openssl

In our Qt project for Android (C++) we want to use gRPC, which includes using OpenSSL as well.

We get the following error when trying to run the application:

**W/System.err(23847): Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: cannot locate symbol "SSL_set_tlsext_host_name" referenced by "/data/app/com.ourapp.service-_IlywsPF_RnagtFsY1ux_Q==/lib/arm/libgrpc.so"...**

Our interpretation of the problem is that gRPC cannot find this function SSL_set_tlsext_host_name. Doing a readelf on the libgrpc.so file shows us that it is "UND", which means it is referenced but not defined.

What we have done is downloading OpenSSL 1.1.1 and compiled that towards Android C++ (API 21), as recommended here: [Qt for Android and BoringSSL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42442688/qt-for-android-and-boringssl). This produced a libssl.so and libcrypto.so. Doing readelf on the libssl.so file shows us that the SSL_set_tlsext_host_name function is indeed defined in that library.

We have linked to libssl, libcrypto and libgrpc (in that order) in Qt Creator, but the error refuses to go away, and this has now become a showstopper for us.

Comment: Which version of Qt are you using, which version of OpenSSL does that use, and is it statically or dynamically linked with OpenSSL?

Comment: Qt is 5.9, dynamic linkage.

Comment: And which libraries are present in the APK? My hypothesis is that Qt is bringing its own, older libssl.

Comment: The newer libssl and libcrypto. Inspected them first thing, thinking it was something like this.

Comment: Any clues in the log about which libssl it is picking up? If you temporarily remove gRPC you should be able to ask Qt which version of OpenSSL is loaded.

Comment: It is picking up the correct one, just double checked. One hypothesis from our side is that DexGuard has something to do with it. Maybe it scrambles the SO file so hard it becomes unusable for linkage..

Comment: You can't use OpenSSL 1.1.1 with Qt 5.9. Use either OpenSSL 1.0 or Qt 5.12.4 / 5.13.0. Also check for the version of android using. You can find more info about supported versions [here](https://github.com/KDAB/android_openssl)

Comment: Seems like that might be the problem then, and OpenSSL 1.0 does not even have the SSL_set_tlsext_host_name function in it, which is bad for us. Thanks for the information, really appreciated.